# QBXML Query for 50000 customers does not work

Tags: enterprise, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbxml

I installed QuickBooks Enterprise 13.0 Trial. 
Imported 50000 customers using the Excel template it provided

Downloaded QB SDKTest.exe from

[https://member.developer.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/samples/readme.html#SDKTest (VB) (qbxml) (desktop)][1]

I have a simple query to request customers

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
   <!DOCTYPE QBXML PUBLIC '-//INTUIT//DTD QBXML QBD 1.0//EN' >
      <QBXML>
         <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
             <CustomerQueryRq requestID = "Customers"> 
                <ActiveStatus>All</ActiveStatus> 
             </CustomerQueryRq> 
         </QBXMLMsgsRq>
      </QBXML>
```

It fails with the following response

```
<CustomerQueryRs statusMessage="There has been an internal error when processing the request." statusSeverity="Error" statusCode="1000" requestID="Customers"/>
```

The test was OK with 40000 customers. Did I reach a limit ? I expected to be able to work with 100000 customers

Answer (score 4):

50K records are quite huge. So,you can try using 'Iterators' for this.

Ref - https://member.developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/doc/PDF/QBSDK_ProGuide.pdf
(Pg - 119)
Please let me know if it works.

You can refer the following link for object limits
http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/articles/INF12412

Thanks

Comment: Here's a qbXML example of iterating through customers with some additional explanation too:  http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_qbxml_customerquery_with_iterators

Comment: Thanks for your answer it helps. iterators based solution was able to return 50k customers in one go (80k hangs), but of course I should define a more reasonable MaxReturned value

Comment: You have to remember that what ever is returned has to be stored in memory until you have processed it. You can look in the SDK logs and estimate how big the response file is based on the number of characters returned.